# php - when using mysqli_fetch_assoc(result), what happens to the result?

Tags: php, mysql

When I have something like this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Does $result now have one less row in it?
If I loop `mysqli_fetch_assoc` through all the `$result`, will it be empty afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$result` is a reference to a SQL result set, which contains all the rows returned in response to your query.  Calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc` simply moves the result set's internal pointer further down the list of rows, eventually pointing to `NULL` (end of list).  The rows are all still there, you haven't removed any of them: you've simply traversed the list, and you could run through them again by using something like `mysqli_data_seek` to reset the internal pointer to a specific row.

To clear `$result`, you'd need to call `mysqli_free_result` to "free" the result set.

Comment: not quite agreeing with the "$result will still contain all the rows that were returned." Instead I would say that it's a reference to the resultset that the SQL has fetched.

Comment: You're correct.  I worded that poorly, which confuses the issue.  I'll edit the answer to incorporate your note.

Answer (score 3):

$result is a [resource pointer](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), it is not possible to add to, or remove data from it. It will give you a result and internally move on to the next record. The result as such is untouched.

The [manual page](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) provides additional info.

Answer (score 1):

After the execution of that line, `$result` remains as a resource pointer, and can be used by other functions where applicable for further processing with `$result` as the reference to the database.

You can either unset it, or `mysqli_free_result($result);`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php